# How to increment the value of each element in the array/list using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

$inc in update works fine for one number -

```
{
     _id:1,
    data:5
}
```

can update data -

```
db.collection.update({}, {$inc:{data:10}}
```

data is sum after updating -

```
{
     _id:1,
    data:15
}
```

However, I can't do it for array of numbers -

```
{
    _id:1,
    data:[1,2,3,4,5,6]
}
```

I need in something like -

```
db.collection.update({}, {$inc:{data:[1,1,1,1,1,1]}}
```

got error -

```
"code" : 14,
"errmsg" : "Cannot increment with non-numeric argument: {pnl: [...]}"
```

Here is the result I need -

```
{
    _id:1,
    data:[2,3,4,5,6,7]
}
```

Could you please suggest me, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [bulk](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/bulk.html#module-pymongo.bulk) API and build your query dynamically using the `[]` operator.

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient()
>>> db = client.test
>>> collection = db.collection
>>> bulk = collection.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
>>> count = 0
>>> for doc in collection.find({'data': {'$exists': True}}):
...     for index, value in enumerate(doc['data']):
...         inc = {}
...         inc['data.'+str(index)] = 1 
...         bulk.find({'_id': doc['_id']}).update_one({'$inc': inc})
...         count = count + 1
...     if count % 150 == 0:
...         bulk.execute() # Execute per 150 operations and  re-init
...         bulk = collection.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
...
>>> if count > 0:
...     bulk.execute() # clean up queues
...
{'writeErrors': [], 'writeConcernErrors': [], 'upserted': [], 'nInserted': 0, 'nUpserted': 0, 'nMatched': 6, 'nModified': 6, 'nRemoved': 0}
>>> list(collection.find())
[{'data': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], '_id': ObjectId('565dc8ec8ec4081174f6161a')}]
>>>
```

You can also do this in the shell like this:

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
for doc in db.collection.find({ 'data': { '$exists': true } }):
    var data = doc.data;
    for (var index=0; index < data.length; index++) {
        var inc = {};
        inc['data.' + i] = 1;
        bulk.find( { '_id': doc._id } ).updateOne( { '$inc': inc } );
    }
    if (count % 200 === 0) {
         bulk.execute();
         bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }

});

if (count > 0)  bulk.execute();
```